# How to get the list of all islamic events of current year using eventkit.framwork in ios

Tags: ios, eventkit

I want to get the list of all Islamic events of current year using Eventkit framework. Used the given below code from stackoverflow but app crashes at NSPredicate line.

```
-(void)showAllEvents
{
  NSDate* endDate =  [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:[[NSDate distantFuture] timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]];
  NSArray *calendarArray1 = [NSArray arrayWithObject:calendar];
  NSPredicate *fetchCalendarEvents = [eventStore predicateForEventsWithStartDate:[NSDate date] endDate:endDate calendars:calendarArray1];
  NSArray *eventList = [eventStore eventsMatchingPredicate:fetchCalendarEvents];

  for(int i=0; i < eventList.count; i++)
    {
      NSLog(@"Event Title:%@", [[eventList objectAtIndex:i] title]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you want the events of the current year, why do you use `distantFuture` from reference date instead of specifying Jan 1st of next year? And what is `calendar`?

Comment: @vadian Thanks for correction. caledar is NScalender type object

Comment: @vadian Well I need events  from first islamic month to last islamic month of current year.Thanks

Comment: And, what it is saying about the crash? Any logs on the debugger console?

Answer (score 0):

`predicateForEventsWithStartDate:endDate:calendars` expects and array of `EKCalendar` objects: you are passing in an `NSCalendar` object.